# how to flush the buffer in TCP connection

Tags: node.js, tcp, tcpclient

Hi I am facing issue with a server client message passing from web client to TCP server . Every time I reconnect to the web page my first 6 messages passes with out delay and the seventh message takes lots of time and the first message repeats again. I think there should be some handler for buffer but I have no idea of how to start it. Help me to solve this. My server and client both are in node socket ( using var net = require('net') ).

Comment: Problem in your *receiving* code. TCP doesn't repeat data.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right place where i have to look. even though this got negative points your comment just made me to realize i haven't returned any response from my client for the ajax call. which is keep on running the same code again and again. a single res.send('success') in client cleared my error. thanks again you saved my day... @EJP

Answer (score -1, accepted):

my client has to send a response for the ajax call which i made from web page:

```
          $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost:3000/client',
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({name:data+'\r'}),// this is the data i get from web page
                    done : function(data){
                        console.log('on success', data);
                    },
                    fail : function(error){
                        console.log('on error', error)
                    }
                })
```

and my node client

```
var net = require('net');
var _ = require('lodash');

   router.post('/client', function(req, res) {
       var inputJSON = req.body;
       var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
       var PORT = 5000;
       var client = new net.Socket();
       client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {

           console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
           // Write a message to the socket as soon as the client is connected, the server will receive it as message from the client 
            _.forEach(inputJSON, function(value,key){
                client.write(value);
                // console.log(value);
             })

        });
    //This is the line i missed in my earlier program the client should respond
    res.send('success')
    });
```

I am learning node. so you can improvise my code with your comments so i can improve better thanks.